# How to resolve type in Kotlin when value is Any?

Tags: android, kotlin

I get `Map<String, Any>` and then I invoke function sendItem() for each key.
Function `sendItem()` can take String, Int or Double. Is it possible to resolve type of value which is `Any`?

```
private fun mapToItems(map: Map<String, Any>?) {
        if (!map.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            map.forEach { key, value ->
                sendItem(key, value)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `when (value) { is String -> ... is Int -> ...  is Double -> ... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you'd need to do some typechecking beforehand if you'd like to avoid runtime errors

```kotlin
map.forEach { key, value ->
  when(value) {
    is String, is Int, is Double -> sendItem(key, value)
    else -> Unit // or any other value
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure this will work if there are separate overloads of `sendItem` -- it's a little ambiguous from the OP.

Comment: True, you'd have to have as many different branches as types in order to get this to work